# How to Create New Columns to Store the Data of the Duplicate ID Column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, format

I have this dataframe:

```
   ID  key
0   1    A
1   1    B
2   2    C
3   3    D
4   3    E
5   3    E
```

I want to create additional `key` columns -as necessary- to store the data in the `key` column when there are duplicate `IDs`

This is a snippet of the output:

```
   ID  key  key2  
0   1    A     B # Note: ID#1 appeared twice in the dataframe, so the key value "B"
                 # associated with the duplicate ID will be stored in the new column "key2"
```

The complete output should like the following:

```
    ID  key  key2   key3
0   1    A      B    NaN
1   2    C    NaN    NaN
2   3    D      E      E # The ID#3 has repeated three times.  The key of                    
                         # of the second repeat "E" will be stored under the "key2" column
                         # and the third repeat "E" will be stored in the new column "key3"
```

Any suggestion or idea how should I approach this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `groupby` and `apply`. Their respective docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). You can `unstack` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)) the extra level of the MultiIndex that is created.

```
df.groupby('ID')['key'].apply(
    lambda s: pd.Series(s.values, index=['key_%s' % i for i in range(s.shape[0])])
).unstack(-1)
```

outputs

```
   key_0 key_1 key_2
ID                  
1      A     B  None
2      C  None  None
3      D     E     E
```

If you want `ID` as a column, you can call `reset_index` on this DataFrame.

Comment: That's amazing!  Would it be possible to make the code handles the same dataframe but with the additional column `AltterKey`, So the dataframe will have 3 columns in total (`ID`, `key`, and `AlterKey`).  How should I modify the code to make it working?
@Alex

Comment: I mean How can I apply the `lambda` function to the new column `AlterKey`?
Thanks, @Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['cols'] = 'key' + df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str)
print (df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='cols', values='key', aggfunc=''.join))
cols key0  key1  key2
ID                   
1       A     B  None
2       C  None  None
3       D     E     E
```