# How to Modify the Dataframe so Each Row Stores All the Data of its Duplicate Rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, series

I have this dataframe with three columns (`ID`,`key`, and `word`)

```
   ID  key   word
0   1    A  Apple
1   1    B  Bug
2   2    C  Cat
3   3    D  Dog
4   3    E  Exogenous
5   3    E  Egg
```

I want to create additional `key` and `word` columns -as necessary- to store the data in the `key` and `word` columns when there are rows with duplicate `IDs`

This is a snippet of the output

```
   ID  key_0  key_1   word_0   word_1  
0   1      A      B    Apple      Bug
```

**Note:** in the output above, the `ID`#`1` appeared twice in the dataframe, so the `"key"` value `"B"` associated with the duplicate `ID` will be stored in the new column `"key_1"`.  The word `Bug` found in the duplicate `ID`#`1` will be stored in the new column `word_1` as well.

The complete output should like the following:

```
    ID  key_0  key_1   key_2   word_0        word_1    word_2
0   1       A      B     NaN    Apple           Bug       NaN
1   2       C    NaN     NaN      Cat           NaN       NaN
2   3       D      E       E      Dog     Exogenous       Egg
```

Notice in the complete output, the `ID`#`3` has repeated three times.  The `key` of the second repeat `"E"` will be stored under the `"key_1"` column and the third repeat `"E"` will be stored in the new column `"key_2"`.  This applies to the words `"Exogenous"` and `"Egg"` in the same mannar.

I found [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38734358/1974919) solution useful, but it only works for the `key` column:

```
df.groupby('ID')['key'].apply(
lambda s: pd.Series(s.values, index=['key_%s' % i for i in range(s.shape[0])])).unstack(-1)
```

Any idea how can I make the lambda function works for both the `key` and `word` columns?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.set_levels((df2.columns.levels[1]).astype(str), level=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().str.join('_')
df2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat after using Alex's solution :

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['key'].apply(
lambda s: pd.Series(s.values, index=['key_%s' % i for i in range(s.shape[0])])).unstack(-1)

df2 = df.groupby('ID')['word'].apply(
lambda s: pd.Series(s.values, index=['word_%s' % i for i in range(s.shape[0])])).unstack(-1)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':df['ID'].unique()})

df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
```

Comment: This gives an error ... `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`  @Gaurav Dhama

Comment: Sorry i forgot that unique() gives an ndarray not a dataframe. Have changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['cols'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].cumcount().astype(str)
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='cols', values=['key','word'], aggfunc=''.join)
df1.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   key_0 key_1 key_2 word_0     word_1 word_2
ID                                           
1      A     B  None  Apple        Bug   None
2      C  None  None    Cat       None   None
3      D     E     E    Dog  Exogenous    Egg
```